# Timeout on kubernetes api server logs

Tags: kubernetes

I've an issue installing k8s with kubespray, the problem is with api server, on start up it complains about some time out errors and goes down.

Bottom line of long error message is like this:

```
logging error output: "k8s\x00\n\f\n\x02v1\x12\x06Status\x12b\n\x04\n\x00\x12\x00\x12\aFailure\x1a9Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration\"\aTimeout*\n\n\x00\x12\x00\x1a\x00(\x002\x000\xf8\x03\x1a\x00\"\x00"
```

Also this is result of health check

```
-> curl localhost:8080/healthz
[+]ping ok
[+]poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers ok
[-]poststarthook/bootstrap-controller failed: reason withheld
[+]poststarthook/extensions/third-party-resources ok
[-]poststarthook/ca-registration failed: reason withheld
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration ok
[-]autoregister-completion failed: reason withheld
healthz check failed
```

I've changed api server manifest and set  --v=5 but still I don't see any useful logs.

How can I debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same problem recently. The health check log is same with you.

Etcd itself is ok, etcdctl can operate it, apiserver shows etcd is ok too.

k8s apiserver log only shows timeout of etcd.

After i check the socket between etcd and apiserver, i found that apiserver had no connection to etcd at all.

so i use check the client-certificates files and found that its validity time is expired.so that apiserver can't establish ssl connection on etcd. But apiserver didn't show the accurate erro.

Hope this help you.